# Irregular spacing with mhchem commands

Tags: spacing, macros, mhchem

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{{}^3He} has a higher vapour pressure, and therefore a lower boiling point, 
than \ce{{}^4He}: the result of this is that pumping away the most energetic 
molecules from the bottom layer preferentially removes \ce{{}^3He}.

\end{document}
```

which yields the (correct) output. (I don't have enough rep to post three images separately!)

Attempting to package the awkward `\ce` command into a custom macro messes up the spacing with the following words, though not with punctuation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\newcommand{\HeThree}{\ce{{}^3He}}
\newcommand{\HeFour}{\ce{{}^4He}}

\begin{document}

\HeThree has a higher vapour pressure, and therefore a lower boiling point, than \HeFour: the result of this is that pumping away the most energetic molecules from the bottom layer preferentially removes \HeThree.

\end{document}
```

Placing a fixed space (`~`) in the macro naturally reverses this, so the punctuation spacing is now incorrect:

```
\newcommand{\HeThree}{\ce{{}^3He}~}
\newcommand{\HeFour}{\ce{{}^4He}~}
```

The outputs of these three arrangements are as follows:

[image]

What is the best way to get a consistent, correct spacing with a macro, that doesn't rely on me manually having to place a `~` after each time the macro precedes a word?

(I have the latest versions of TeXLive and mhchem installed)

Comment: This isn't a bug, but just the nature of the way TeX digests macro names (it thus has nothing to do with `mhchem`).  The proper usage (in your 2nd code segment) is, thus, `\HeThree{} has a higher...`.  Otherwise, the trailing space is considered a terminating token for `\HeThree` rather than a space in its own right.

Comment: `\def\definece#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname ce:#1\endcsname{\ce{#2}}}` and `\def\cn#1{\csnanme ce:#1\endcsname}` would let you define (`\definece{he3}{{}^3He}`)keywords and use `\cn{he3}` or whatever name you choose. I think it will be clear and you won't need to take care of the space after the macro.

Comment: Both of the comments make sense, thank you! I am a bit disappointed that then there is no way of making a "clean" macro in this case...

Comment: What do you mean with clean? Manuel's suggestion is very clean.

Comment: @TeXnician that is true (I am currently using it, although I had to correct `\csnanme`); I meant in the sense that one could just type `\hethree` without any braces. But I guess even LaTeX convenience has its limits ;)

Comment: As mentioned above, LaTeX eating up spaces after macros is a common pitfall and is handled early on in every LaTeX introduction. // Use `\ce{^3He}` instead of `\ce{{}^3He}`. // Find alternatives for things you find awkward.

Comment: You can use your definition and the `xspace` package: `\newcommand{\HeThree}{\ce{^3He}\xspace}`. This addresses the issue.

Comment: Argh, how embarrassing! I've never used custom macros for text shorthand, so I've never had this issue and thought it was specific to mhchem... thank you for the responses anyway, I have now done my reading!